# In Scrapy, how to write two spiders with the same parse method without code repetition?

Tags: python, scrapy, dry

I'd like to write write two spiders in Scrapy with different [start_requests](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) methods, but exactly the same [parse](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse) method. However, since `parse` is an instance method, I'm not sure how to 'copy' it from one spider to the other without simply copy-pasting all the code. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inherence like in any other case:

```
class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse(self, request):
        pass # Common parse code

class SpiderOne(BaseSpider):

    def start_requests(self):
        pass # Code for this spider

class SpiderTwo(BaseSpider):

    def start_requests(self):
        pass # Code for other spider
```

Answer (score 1):

any method is function like `fun(the_self, other_args...)`. So you can implement your common code as function with `self` argument but outside any classes. Then call it by passing this `self` as first argument.